# NullPointerException when trying to set background color of WebView removed from screen

Tags: android, exception, asynchronous, webview

The app places *WebView* on screen with some preloaded content. There is data download running in background. When this data is ready, the *WebView* is being setup.
The problem occurs if the user switches to other activity while data download is in progress:

```
void onDataLoaded() {
    WebView wv = getWebView();
    if (wv != null) {
        wv.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.Black));
```

And the exception is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.webkit.WebViewClassic.setBackgroundColor(WebViewClassic.java:8852)
    at android.webkit.WebView.setBackgroundColor(WebView.java:2210)
    at com.sample.app.TestActivity.onDataLoaded(TestActivity:45)
```

How can I prevent this crash if the WebView has been removed from the screen?

Comment: do       `wv.setBackgroundColor( getApplicationContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.Black));`

Comment: Context.getResources().getColor(int) has been deprecated. Recommended replacement is _ContextCompat_.

Comment: how did you know?? and where is _Google_ documented it?

Comment: *WebView has been removed from the screen* what do you mean by *removed from the screen*?

Comment: Sorry. You are correct. Google recommends using _getColor(int, Theme)_: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColor(int, android.content.res.Resources.Theme). The support for this call though comes in SDK 23+ which is not my case. I am targeting 17+. This still does should prevent the crash, as the crash happens in _WebView.setBackgroundColor()_ which receives non-null _int_ as a parameter.